# change in JSON function to make it work?

Tags: java, android, json

I called JSON url like this:

```
jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.0.219:90/flexlocation2");
Utils.log("json function: " + jsonobject);
```

but that json function return null,
and produce Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value !DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

here is my JSON :

```
{"flexlocation":[{"flex_id":"12","name":"Jawa Barat"},{"flex_id":"17","name":"Bali"},{"flex_id":"11","name":"DKI Jakarta"},{"flex_id":"16","name":"Banten"}]}
```

After that I check JSONfunctions class, here is JSONfunctions class that I got from a tutorial :

```
public class JSONfunctions {

public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    // Download JSON data from URL
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // Convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
}
```

the error come from this line :

```
catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
```

I search for answer, and it wrote that it come from this "flex_id":"12".
It wrote that it should be like this "flex_id":12.
Without "".

For information :
when I log from my json result, the result is !DOCTYPE html.

But when I change the json from original tutorial : http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt , the result log is {

What make it different result (!DOCTYPE html with {) when my json and tutorial json is the same json array format with array name?

So, what must I add to JSONfunctions on line jArray = new JSONObject(result); to make it work with ""? Change in result = sb.toString();?

Comment: Means problem is with `flexlocation2` API

Comment: it seems so, I try to string replace with result_awal = sb.toString();
   result_akhir = result_awal.replace("<!DOCTYPE html>", "{"); also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your sb.toString() value. If it returns the answer in correct format as you specified, then convert the result into JSONObject. If there is error in reading sb.toString() then the error is in JSON result.
2. DOCTYPE error occurs when there is syntax error in your json response. Try this,

   JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(result);
   JSONArray array=obj.getJSONArray("flexlocation");
   for(int i=0;i*<*array.length();i++)
   {
   JSONObject object=array.getJSONObject(i);
   String flexid=object.getString("flex_id");
   String name=object.getString("name");
   }